# Php drop down selection from 2 tables

Tags: php, html, sql

I've created a php page that includes a form which filters a MySQL table data with dropdown selection and display them below. The selection combines the data from 2 LEFT JOINED tables (suppliers & suppliers_expenses - supplier_Id is common field) and GET the total sum expenses.

The problem I'm trying to solve, is how to select the specific selection from the form and show it in the table data. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code I use:

```
<body>

    <form name="myForm" action="expenses_Supplier.php"  method="post">
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("dbserver","user","****","***");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $query = "SELECT suppliers.Supplier_id,Name
    FROM suppliers
    LEFT JOIN expenses_suppliers
    ON suppliers.Supplier_id=expenses_suppliers.Supplier_id
    ORDER BY Name;"; //Write a query
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $query);  //Execute the query
    ?>
    <table  bgcolor="silver" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" style="width: 450px">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 155px"><B>Name:</B></td>
    <td><select name="Supplier_id">
    <?php
    while($fetch_options = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
    ?>
    <option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['Supplier_id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options['Supplier_id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['Name']; ?></option>
    <!--Echo out options-->
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 155px"><input type="submit" value="ΑΝΑΖΗΤΗΣΗ"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <br />
    
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("dbserver","user","****","***");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT suppliers.Name, expenses_suppliers.*
    FROM suppliers
    LEFT JOIN expenses_suppliers
    ON suppliers.Supplier_id=expenses_suppliers.Supplier_id
    where expenses_suppliers.Supplier_id=3  <== HERE IS MY PROBLEM 
    order by datepicker;");
    
    
    echo "<table border='1' width='98%' bgcolor='#f1f1f1'>";  
    echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
    echo "<td width='400' align='center'>ΥΠΟΛΟΙΠΟ</td>";  
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(DIFFERENCE) AS sup_ammount FROM expenses_suppliers where Supplier_id=3");  <== HERE IS MY PROBLEM 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))  
    {  
    echo "<td class='cell'>" . $row['sup_ammount'] . "</td>";
    }  
    echo "</table>";
      
    echo "<table border='1' width='98%'>
    <tr>
    <!-- <th>A/A</th> -->
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
    <th>AMMOUNT</th>
    <th>CREDIT</th>
    <th>DIFFERENCE</th>
    </tr>";
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      /* echo "<td>" . $row['Number'] . "</td>"; */
      echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class='cell'>" . $row['datepicker'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class='cell'>" . $row['Ammount'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class='cell'>" . $row['Credit'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class='cell'>" . $row['DIFFERENCE'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?> 

    </body>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "select the specific selection"? Do you ask for the code in expenses_Supplier.php?

Comment: Have you tried doing $variable = $_POST['Supplier_id']; ? That's how you retrieve the selected dropdown value from your form after submission.

Comment: Select the specific selection submitted by the form. If the drop down shows 10 results, select one from them and collect all the data.

Comment: How do i insert $variable = $_POST['Supplier_id']; in WHERE statement in my query?

Comment: You can't do it at once. because you need the user's choice before being able to show the right data. You can "select" everything and use some javascript to show or hide rows or you can create another page to collect the right information (you can create a new page or use some xhr/ajax to display result without having to load the page again).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [mysqli prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php) and bind the Supplier_id value